# Are "put" and "have put" both grammatically correct, and do they mean the same thing?

Tags: grammaticality

Are "put" and "have put" both grammatically correct?

> You put me in an awkward position.

> You have put me in an awkward position.

Do both of the above sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: You mean "**You** put me..."

Comment: "You put me" can also be short for "You had put me" for a condition that has since been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the present participle 'putting', the verb to put doesn't have any other forms - past and future participles are the same as the infinite (I put, I will put).

Context nearly always makes the tense clear, but ambiguity is possible.

For example:

- You put me in a difficult position when you **did** that.
- You put me in a difficult position when you **do** that.

One clear difference is that "have put" can only be used in the past tense; that is to say, the 'putting' has already been done. This is because, when you use 'have' as an auxiliary verb it can only be the past or present tense, so combined with 'put' it can only be the past.